# Improved Perlin noise "too smooth"

Tags: random, lua, noise, perlin-noise, love2d

I've finally managed to write a working Lua version of Perlin's improved noise for Love 2D. However, when I run it, I get this:

[image]

Which is just fine, I guess. But I would like something that looks more like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic Perlin noise cloud is generated by summing together multiple octaves of noise - each octave has a frequency & an amplitude. The typical approach is to double the frequency & halve the amplitude with every iteration. Refer to this question on [How to get more gentle (cloud like) noise?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/95418/how-to-get-more-gentle-cloud-like-noise) & [Amit's terrain from noise demos](http://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/) if you need more details.

Answer (score 4):

The first picture is a correct Perlin noise with big granularity.
The second picture looks like a sum of two (or three?) Perlin noises: with big granularity and with small granularity.